# How load html from URL?

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, html-parser

i have problem and if someone can help me please.
i want to load html.

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = webGet.Load(@"https://example.com/search_engine/jobs.cgi?owner=5027409&ownertype=fair&posting_code=612");
```

i using htmlagilitypack but it can't load html. I download html in my local PC and it load from there.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Is this a Console, Web, XAML/WPF or WinForms app?

Comment: it is in web. asp.net website

Answer (score 2):

You're overdoing it a little.
All you need is:

```
//using for IDisposable.Dispose()
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string html = client.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com");
    //Do something with html then
}
```

Comment: @TemoGelashvili Its always helpful to describe the problem instead of saying "it doesn't work"

Comment: Sorry... I mean it doesn't work for my link. here is link and please have a look. it work for others links but not for my link :(

Comment: @TemoGelashvili When it doesn't work: What do you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: @TemoGelashvili What is the content you got back?

Comment: This is what i got back--->  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><HTML lang=en><HEAD><TITLE>WCN ATS</TITLE><META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=https://atsv7.wcn.co.uk/search_engine/jobs.cgi?owner=5027409&ownertype=fair&posting_code=612"></HEAD><BODY>

Comment: @TemoGelashvili So, what exactly are you expecting? I mean, when you request something from a URL, you're going to get back the contents of that page. But it sounds like you're expecting to receive rendered content, such as what you actually see in a web browser. Am I correct in assuming this?

Comment: @TemoGelashvili What are you trying to achieve by requesting data from that URL? Are you going to parse that data using HTMLAgilityPack? If so, then I think you need to be asking a different question.